# Setting no-referrer no-opener and no-follow using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, referrer, window.opener, nofollow, referrer-policy

I want `no-referrer`, `no-opener` and `no-follow` for globe of my website. For all the pages and URLs. So, I thought doing with `.htaccess`

Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
    Header set X-Opener-Policy "no-opener"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=REL_HEADER:nofollow]
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "nofollow" env=REL_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

I never heard of using `no-follow` and `no-opener` with `.htaccess`. will this work?

Comment: Is this your complete `.htaccess` file? Where did you get `X-Opener-Policy` from?

Comment: @MrWhite `ChatGTP` provided it. So, this code is wrong?

Comment: @MrWhite and yes, this is my complete `.htaccess` file

Comment: @MrWhite any update? how to do this?